# have radio button on list item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have a `ListView` :

```
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

The layout of **each item row** of the list view is:

```
<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android: orientation = "horizontal" 
    android: layout_width = "fill_parent" 
    android: layout_height = "fill_parent" 
    > 
    <ImageView 
          android: id = "@+id/my_img" 
          android: layout_width = "wrap_content" 
          android: layout_height = "wrap_content" 
          android: layout_gravity = "center_vertical"          
          /> 
    <TextView 
         android: id = "@+id/my_value" 
         android: layout_width = "wrap_content" 
         android: layout_height = "wrap_content" 
         android: textColor = "@drawable/ black" /> 
</ LinearLayout>
```

As you see above, each **row** of the list consists of a `ImageView` and a `TextView` . Now, I would like to have a **radio button** next to the `TextView` , how to add radio button in my case?

Comment: Use `Relativelayout` and `add <RadioButton /> end of Textview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android: layout_width = "fill_parent" 
    android: layout_height = "fill_parent" 
    > 
    <ImageView 
          android: id = "@+id/my_img" 
          android: layout_width = "wrap_content" 
          android: layout_height = "wrap_content" 
          android:layout_algnParentLeft="true" 
          android: layout_centerVertical = "true"          
          /> 
    <TextView 
         android: id = "@+id/my_value" 
         android: layout_width = "wrap_content" 
         android: layout_height = "wrap_content" 
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/my_img"
         android: textColor = "@drawable/ black" /> 
    <RadioButton 
         android: id = "@+id/radio" 
         android: layout_width = "wrap_content" 
         android: layout_height = "wrap_content" 
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/my_value" /> 

</ RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Vipin can you explain us what's the question is?

Comment: @robinhood Leem.fin has edited his question after my answer dont know why

Comment: he had given an xml and he was asking how to add radio in front of text view